# Validating a Model Property is Greater than Another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

First, let me say I am *extremely* new to Rails (toyed with it a time or two but forcing myself to write a complete project with it now, started on it yesterday).

I am now trying to validate that a model property (terminology?) is greater than another. This appeared to be a perfect instance for `validates_numericality_of` with the `greater_than` option, but alas that throws an error telling me `greater_than expects a number, not a symbol`. If I try to typecast that symbol `.to_f` I get an `undefined method` error.

Here is what I eventually did and I am curious as to whether there is a better way. It's just a simple system to control project releases, we only have major/minor releases (one-dot) so float felt like the right decision here.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_numericality_of :current_release
    validates_numericality_of :next_release
    validate :next_release_is_greater

    def next_release_is_greater
        errors.add_to_base("Next release must be greater than current release") unless next_release.to_f > current_release.to_f
    end
end
```

This works - it passes the relevant unit test (below for your viewing pleasure), I'm just curious as to if there is an easier way - something I could have tried otherwise.

Relevant unit test:

```
# Fixture data:
#   PALS:
#     name: PALS
#     description: This is the PALS project
#     current_release: 1.0
#     next_release: 2.0
#     project_category: 1
#     user: 1
def test_release_is_future
    project = Project.first(:conditions => {:name => 'PALS'})
    project.current_release = 10.0
    assert !project.save

    project.current_release = 1.0
    assert project.save
end
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As you noticed, the only way is to use a custom validator.
The :greater_than option should be an integer. The following code won't work because both current and next release are available only at instance-level.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_numericality_of :current_release
  validates_numericality_of :next_release, :greater_than => :current_release
end
```

The purpose of the `greater_than` option is to validate the value against a static constant or an other class method.

So, don't mind and go ahead with your custom validator. :)

Comment: Excellent answer, detailed response - just what I needed (plus a little reassurance).

Comment: Great answer, please fix spelling error when you have a chance "greather_than".  Thanks again.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti can you please amend your answer, this is in fact possible in reasonably recent Rails versions and works as expected. So custom validator is not needed anymore.

Comment: At this point, given that the question isn't tagged with a specific Rails version, this answer is simply wrong. It states *"this wouldn't work"*, at the same time that is the exact way to do it in modern versions of Rails.

Answer (score 13):

`validates_numericality_of` accepts [a large list of options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_numericality_of) and some of them can be supplied with a proc or a symbol(this means you can basically pass an attribute or an entire method).

to validate the numericality of a property is higher than another value:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_numericality_of :current_release, less_than: ->(project) { project.next_release }

  validates_numericality_of :next_release, 
    greater_than: Proc.new { project.current_release }
end
```

To clarify, any of these options can accept a proc or symbol:

- `:greater_than`
- `:greater_than_or_equal_to`
- `:equal_to :less_than`
- `:less_than_or_equal_to`

**validates_numericality docs:** http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_numericality_of

**using procs with validations:**
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless

Answer (score 9):

With Rails 3.2, you can validate two fields against each other on the fly by passing in a proc.

```
validates_numericality_of :next_release, :greater_than => Proc.new {|project| project.current_release }
```

Answer (score -2):

That's the best way to execute custom validation, however, you might want to look into something like factory_girl as a replacement to fixtures (which it looks like you are using):

http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

Your unit test would then look like:

```
def test_...
    Factory.create(:project, :current_release => 10.0)
    assert !Factory.build(:project, :current_release => 1.0).valid?
end
```